# MySQL - How do I figure out which columns to index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

How do I figure out which columns to index?

```
SELECT a.ORD_ID AS Manual_Added_Orders,
   a.ORD_poOrdID_List AS Auto_Added_Orders,
   a.ORDPOITEM_ModelNumber,
   a.ORDPO_Number,
   a.ORDPOITEM_ID,
   (SELECT sum(ORDPOITEM_Qty) AS ORDPOITEM_Qty
      FROM orderpoitems
     WHERE     ORDPOITEM_ModelNumber = a.ORDPOITEM_ModelNumber
           AND ORDPO_Number = 123007)
      AS ORDPOITEM_Qty,
   a.ORDPO_TrackingNumber,
   a.ORDPOITEM_Received,
   a.ORDPOITEM_ReceivedQty,
   a.ORDPOITEM_ReceivedBy,
   b.ORDPO_ID
FROM orderpoitems a
   LEFT JOIN orderpo b ON (a.ORDPO_Number = b.ORDPO_Number)
WHERE a.ORDPO_Number = 123007
GROUP BY a.ORDPOITEM_ModelNumber
ORDER BY a.ORD_poOrdID_List, a.ORD_ID
```

[image]

I did the explain that is how I am getting these pictures... I added a few indexes... still not looking good.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the "EXPLAIN" feature in mysql. It helps a lot to understand how queries are optimized my the engine.

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly your query could be simplified to:

```
SELECT a.ORD_ID AS Manual_Added_Orders,
 a.ORD_poOrdID_List AS Auto_Added_Orders,
 a.ORDPOITEM_ModelNumber,
 a.ORDPO_Number,
 a.ORDPOITEM_ID,
 SUM(ORDPOITEM_Qty) AS ORDPOITEM_Qty
 a.ORDPO_TrackingNumber,
 a.ORDPOITEM_Received,
 a.ORDPOITEM_ReceivedQty,
 a.ORDPOITEM_ReceivedBy,
 b.ORDPO_ID
FROM orderpoitems a
LEFT JOIN orderpo b ON (a.ORDPO_Number = b.ORDPO_Number)
WHERE a.ORDPO_Number = 123007
GROUP BY a.ORDPOITEM_ModelNumber
ORDER BY a.ORD_poOrdID_List, a.ORD_ID
```

Secondly I would start by creating a index on the `orderpoitems.ORDPO_Number` and `orderpo.ORDPO_number`

Bit hard to say without the table structures.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [indexes and covering index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)

From what you have, start with what is in your where clause AND join criteria to another table.  Also, include if possible and practical, those columns used in group by / order by as order by is typically a killer when finishing a query.

That said, I would have an index on your OrderPOItems table on

( ordpo_number, orderpoitem_ModelNumber, ord_poordid_list, ord_id )

This way, the FIRST element hits your WHERE clause.  Next the column for your data grouping, finally, the columns for your order by.  This way, the joins and qualifying components can be "covered" from the index alone without having to go to the raw data pages for the rest of the columns being returned.  Hopefully a good jump start specific to your scenario.